# Can't widen Chrome or Firefox with vertical monitor

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows

I work with my monitor in a portrait/vertical orientation. One site I need to use has a button on the top-right which is invisible/unreachable, and there is no scroll bar. When I enter windowed mode, I can position the window partially off of the left hand side of the screen; but when I try to extend the width of the window on its right-hand edge, I find that I cannot make the window wider. This is the case on both Chrome and Firefox, and it seems to be this way for every site I try. I'm left thinking that it could be to do with the monitor orientation, but I have no idea. Is there any way to widen my browser window? I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a Windows limitation based on the number of monitors and orientation. I have two monitors and I am able to widen Firefox past the size of my monitor. Once I disconnect my second monitor, I am no longer able to do so.

## Firefox Responsive Design Mode

One workaround is to use Firefox's [Responsive Design Mode](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/responsive_design_mode/). This is usually used to test responsiveness in different screen sizes.

To enable this mode, use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> or you can enable it in DevTools.

[image: DevTools]

Then you can set the width to whatever value you want and you can scroll freely.

[image: Responsive Design Mode]

## Chrome Device Mode

The same exists in Chrome, known as [Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/).

I think the only difference is that Chrome requires DevTools to be open to use this mode, so the shortcut to enable this would be <kbd>F12</kbd>, then separately <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.